# PDFTK server issues. Pdf file can't be sent to print in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdftk

I'm using PDFTK server to generate pdf files in a website. Is a Linux environment and it was working fine until now. The pdf file is generated but when the user is using Chrome to view the pdf file, the print button doesn't do anything. If the user uses Firefox, no problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add `allow printing` in your pdftk command :

https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

> pdftk 1.pdf output 1.128.pdf owner_pw foo user_pw baz allow printing